# time_select helper and Time object creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
  .row
    = f.label       :start_time
    = time_select :model, :start_time, { minute_step: 30 }
  .row
    = f.label           :end_time
    = time_select :model, :end_time, { minute_step: 30 }
```

time_select generates 2 selects for each copy( 1 for hours and 1 for minutes). As result we have 'model' hash in params with 'start_time(1i)', ... 'start_time(5i)' fields (the same for end_time). I have the following questions:

1. How can I create a new Time object from this hash?
2. Is it possible to create only one select for each time_select?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I create a new Time object from this hash?

You can let Rails do the work for you:

```
= f.time_select(:start_time, minute_step: 30)
```

When you call `update_attributes` on your model in the controller, Rails will create the Time object and assign it to the model.

If you use Rails 4, be sure to whitelist `:start_time` and `:end_time` using the strong parameters.

#### Is it possible to create only one select for each time_select?

By default, Rails can't do this. However, you can use the [combined_time_select](https://github.com/excid3/combined_time_select) gem to do it for you:

```
f.time_select(:end_time, combined: true, minute_step: 30)
```

Be sure to restart your Rails server after installing this gem.

Answer (score 0):

These helpers are optimised for use with a ActiveRecord model and its attributes. If you have the columns `start_time` and `end_time`, you should not need to worry about creating the Time object from the passed params yourself.

What are you specifically trying to achieve?